# How to remove object inside an array which is inside an object in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an mongodb collection like:

```
{
    _id: "xxxxxxxxx",
    name:"john",
    friends: [
    {post: {_id:111111}},
    {post: {_id:22222}},
    {post: {_id:333}}
    ]
  }
```

Now i need to delete post with id 11111.
How can I achieve this.

**UPDATE**
my controller function is like:

```
User.updateOne(
        { _id: req.headers.id },
        {
            $pull: {
                newCart: { "post._id": id._id },
            },
        },
        { new: true }
    ).then((res) => console.log(res, user));
```

newCart is like friends,its an array.

My actual document looks like this,i want to delete post with the matched id.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kTWK.png)

Comment: Not sure, what is `id._id` in your screenshot? `post._id` is a string and not ObjectId, may be this can be an issue?

Comment: if `id` is Mongoose instance, try to pass string into query: `id.id` or `id._id.toString()`

Comment: look at this:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71831799/how-to-delete-object-inside-an-array-in-mongodb-collection)

even if i pass plane id values,it does not updates in my database
@Kuzzy

Comment: Hm, does your mongoose connected to the same DB as client in which you are looking for result? You can try simple test. Just make a `findOne` request after update and see what it returns, smth like that: `User.updateOne(...).then((res) => { User.findOne({ _id: req.headers.id }).then((updatedResult) => console.log(updatedResult)) } )`

Comment: its not changing anything,I dont find anything wrong with the query too,dont know where i am messing up.

Comment: Does any other requests changing something? For example `User. findByIdAndUpdate(req.headers.id, { $set: { name: 'Changed name'} })`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$pull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator, with mongoose it will look something like that:

```js
await User.updateOne({ _id: 'xxxxxxxxx' }, { $pull: { friends: { 'post._id': 11111 } } })
```

UPD:
[image]
[image]

Comment: its not updating,it gives response as:
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}

Comment: It says that record was updated (modifiedCount: 1), which result you are expecting?

Comment: But its not actually updating in my database

Comment: also if i pass any id in {"post._id": anyid} it still says modifiedCount as 1

Comment: See updated answer, it works perfect, maybe you are missed something. Can you share your code?

Comment: I have updated my controller function in the question,you see it once

Comment: look at the image that I updated in the question.