# How to delete object inside an array in mongodb collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have a controller function as:

```
User.updateOne(
    { _id: "6252d87e010b3f94adcf4e41" },
            {
                $pull: {
                    newCart: {
                        "post._id": "6249e216c1e3b6ae2d4aa273",
                    },
                },
            },
            {new:true}
        ).then((res) => console.log(res, user));
```

The response is like this:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

It shows modifiedCount to 1 but never changes in my realtime database collection.

My collection looks like this:
[Image of my db collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3YHo.png)

Comment: The query is correct https://mongoplayground.net/p/wLF9NrSWcII

Comment: yes,I have also written the same but not updating in my database

Comment: You need to make sure the data types for the `_id` and `""post._id"` fields in the query filters are same as the data types in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The query is correct maybe try adding exec

```
User.updateOne(
  { _id: "6252d87e010b3f94adcf4e41" },
  {
    $pull: {
      newCart: {
        "post._id": "6249e216c1e3b6ae2d4aa273",
      },
    },
  },
  { new: true }
)
  .exec()
  .then((res) => console.log(res, user));
```

Hope this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

your query is completely fine. disconnect your database and try to connect again. after restart maybe this will work